# Allocting IMediaSample for huge video samples

Tags: directshow

I'm writing a DirectShow Video splitter/demuxer filter for an embedded system.

In Audio all audio samples have the same size, small, ~5-8 KB (Each audio sample fits in DATA_PACKET_MAX_SIZE), so I allocate 200 buffers of DATA_PACKET_MAX_SIZE KB, calling RequestAllocator(...).

In Video the video samples behave differently, ranging between 100-160,000 bytes!!!

**Edit:**
I know the size of the MAX sample (Video and Audio) before the splitting starts, before setting my allocator properties, but it sounds almost criminal to hold from an embedded system so much resources...

Should I create a specific IMemAllocator, on-demand, for each 'large' video sample?

Should I create a few IMemAllocators, holding pools of different size buffers?

Thanks,
Rami

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard memory allocator works in a way that you set allocator properties, that is fixed buffer size and buffer count, and then commit operator allocates real memory and you cannot change it. There are two issues with this approach: the first is that you choose buffer size before possibly starting reading real data, and the other one is that if small amount of samples need much larger buffers than other - which is typical with temporal compression formats like H.264 - then you need to have all buffers large and you need to allocate much more memory than you actually need.

There are several ways to address the problem.

The cleanest way is to implement custom memory allocator where you can allocate/reallocate buffers on runtime to satisfy unexpectedly large allocations. It is the output pin who chooses memory allocator, so you are in position to mount yours and you are good to go.

Another way which is more or less safe and which is used by some popular filters is to decommit and commit the allocator again on runtime when you need a larger buffer. That is, once you see on runtime that your payload does not fit the buffer, you decommit the allocator, update its properties, commit it back and continue as if nothing has happened at all. This normally works but is not as clean as the first method.

Then with many filters you can voluntary allocate non-allocator media sample and deliver it downstream. This is less safe, this is not how it was supposed to work in first place, but this works out well still in many scenarios.

Comment: Thanks Roman. You hit exactly the possibilities I was playing with! 1. Just after posting the Q I Plunged deeper into the media headers and found the MAX_MEDIA_OBJECT_SIZE, so I can update my allocator's ALLOCATOR_PROPERTIES struct; I edited my Q. 2. The latter suggestion is the same as pre-allocating the largest size; it doesn't matter if I  do it on the beginning, or after 10 minutes of a movie... 3. The 'custom allocator' seems like the correct solution, but, is allocating "on demand" a quick operation?

Comment: Given the speed of computers today, this runtime allocation is just fine. This API is from 90s when it was way more important. With your custom mem allocator you definitely can tune the memory usage to now waste the resources for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this suggestion will not work for some reason in your environment, but here is one idea:

Create an array of two elements for `IMediaSample` pointers. Set both elements to 0. When you need the first element for the first time, check against `NULL` and create an instance of `IMediaSample`, else simply use that media sample and pass it to the next filter. Same for the second, and iterate circularly. Note that this will work `ONLY` if some downstream filter is not holding the `IMediaSmaple` for a long time (async processing, etc...). You can check that by checking the reference count (and you will probably see heavy artifacts in video if that's the case).
Penalty is that extra frame holding the memory, but if you can afford it, you will not have to allocate memory for each new `IMediaSample`.

As I said, this might not be usable in your environment.....

Comment: Hi, thanks. It'll not work. The Downstream filter holds many Media Samples (over 50 Videos till the first Audio arrives). I must allocate a pool of over 100 Media Samples.